# How can I cancel the default action when the 'drop' occurs using Dojo dnd

Tags: drag-and-drop, dojo

I am using dojo/dnd/source.In my application, I drag a item from source to target,and under some conditions,I want to cancel the default action when or before I drop it.

I tried to return false in the onDrop handler,but it doesn't work.
I tried to do "this.emit('dndCancel')",and it doesn't work neither.

```js
myTarget.on("Drop",function(source,nodes,copy){
  this.emit("dndCancel");
  return false;
}
```

What should I do?Please

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Try with a dojo publish:

```
require(['dojo/topic'], function(topic) {
    topic.publish("/dnd/cancel");
}
```